# Trying to connect postgresql heroku with play

Tags: postgresql, heroku, jdbc, playframework

I'm trying to use heroku postgresql with play framework (version 2.5.9) but it doesn't work...

build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
javaJdbc,
cache,
javaWs,
javaJpa,
"org.webjars" % "bootstrap" % "2.3.1",
"org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "5.2.3.Final",
"postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901-1.jdbc4"
)
```

conf/application.conf

```
ebean.default = ["models.*"]
db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
db.default.url="postgres://ambpfzhcrpupmx:PeSnt07zQFVWKQrsqcRd1GzW6I@ec2-54-227-245-197.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d4i5fck68498ce"
default.username = hereMyUserNameFromHeroku
default.password = "hereMyPassNameFromHeroku"
```

I obtain :
 `Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "78.192.102.83", user "ambpfzhcrpupmx", database "d4i5fck68498ce", SSL off`

I dont' understand why...

I'm trying to add "?ssl=true" at the end of my url but it doesn't work too... I obtain : 
`Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`

Anybody can help me plz ? Thank :)

Comment: What cert do you get from the db server? Are you sure that's trusted from your heroku app's perspective? If not, you may need to add that to your truststore.

Answer (score 0):

First, reset your Postgres username and password because you've posted them publicly and anyone can access your database now. Run this command:

```
$ heroku pg:credentials DATABASE --reset
```

Then change your `conf/application.conf` to use the `JDBC_DATABASE_URL` environment variable as per the [Play Framework documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ProductionHeroku#connecting-to-a-database).

```
db.default.url=${?JDBC_DATABASE_URL}
db.default.username=${?JDBC_DATABASE_USERNAME}
db.default.password=${?JDBC_DATABASE_PASSWORD}
```

The underlying problem is that your database URL does not enable SSL, and your Postgres JDBC dependency is too old for it to be turned on automatically. I recommend updating to this:

```
"org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.4.1211"
```